# Prove that there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, weierstrass-approximation

I've been stuck on the following problem for a some time but have it started somewhat and not sure whether it is correct or how to proceed.

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Prove that there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$

I know that since $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, then applying the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem there exists a sequence $(p_n)$ of polynomials such that $p_n \to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Then,

Considering a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ which converges uniformly to $f$.

If we let  $q_n(x)=p_n(x)+f(a)-p_n(a)$.

Then $q_n(a)=f(a)$, $q_n$ must be a polynomial and

$$ |q_n(x)-f(x)| \leq |p_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(a)-p_n(a)|$$
which proves that $q_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

So is this enough to prove that there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$?

Comment: "applying the Weierstrass Approximation theorem, there exists a sequence $(p_n)$ of polynomials such that $p_n\to f$ uniformly on $[a,b].$" Is this conclusion not exactly what you're trying to prove?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen ah yes I got a little confused, would you be able to help me out?

Comment: Not really as it's unclear what help is needed. You are correct that the Weierstrass approximation theorem says that there is a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly to $f$. And that's what you're trying to prove. The proof is done.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen so then all I need to say is, since $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, then applying the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem there exists a sequence $(p_n)$ of polynomials such that $p_n \to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$. ? seems a little short

Comment: Whether you've 'played by the rules' for whatever exercise this is is less clear. Perhaps you were given a different formulation of the Weierstrass approximation theorem and you need to show explicitly that it implies the existence of that sequence. Perhaps the exercise is to prove the Weierstrass approximation.

Comment: It does seem a little short. See my followup comment.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen isn't the Weierstrass approximation, Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. then for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

Comment: Okay, if that's the version you've been given then you need to show it implies that there's a sequence of polys that converges uniformly to f. Hint: for each $n,$ choose the polynomial $p_n$ whose existence is guaranteed by the above theorem for $\epsilon = 1/n.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen could you submit a answer? I am not quite sure what you mean by this and am reviewing this question for a exam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Once we pick our polynomials $p_n$, to prove uniform convergence we must show there is an $N$ such that $|f(x)-p_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and all $x\in[0,1].$

Consider an arbitrary integer $n$. By the Weierstrass approximation theorem (as you stated it in the comments), we can choose a polynomial $p_n$ that satisfies $|p_n(x)-f(x)| < 1/n$ for all $x\in[0,1].$ Choose $p_n$ this way for all $n.$

Now, pick an integer $N >1/\epsilon.$ Then for any $n>N,$ we have $|p_n(x)-f(x)|< \frac{1}{n}<1/N < \epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1].$

Comment: thanks very much, so this completes the full details of the proof? and we do not need to choose a particular pn?

Comment: @jh123  You choose them to get closer and closer to $f$ as $n$ increases (close in the sense that $|f-p_n|$ is small for all $x$). You can choose polynomials arbitrarily close by your statement of the Weierstrass approximation theorem. There aren't explicit polynomials to pick (if that's what you mean), just those whose existence the theorem guarantees. (Actually, there are explicit polynomials one can pick https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial , but I doubt you need a constructive proof here.)