# Show $f$ is the uniform limit of $p_n\circ \cos,$ where the $p_n$ are polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity, weierstrass-approximation

> If $f : [−\pi, \pi]$ is continuous and even on $[−\pi, \pi],$ show there exists a polynomial sequence $\{p_n\}$ such that $p_n\circ\cos$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $[−\pi, \pi]$

I was trying to use theorem of Weiestrass aproximation but I don´t know how to do it.  As a hint it says consider the function $g : [−1, 1] \to\Bbb R$  define as $g := f \circ\arccos$.

Please, help me.

Comment: Let me know if I made any mistake while editing.

Comment: it is correct thank u

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3320628/721644) help? Or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3320695/721644)? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3887228/721644) might also be a bit related.

Comment: Since $\cos(x)$ is even and on $[-\pi,\pi]$ in particular, maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2882242/721644) might be useful. Then, indeed, $g:=f\circ\arccos$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: And maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2200722/721644).